# the issue about rails 3 can't start the application on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I using the rails by Instantrails on windows.It can run well before I update the rails version to rails 3 .
  The error message is :
 E:\InstantRails-2.0-win\rails_apps\myproject>rails server
E:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/lo
ckfile_parser.rb:48:in `parse_source': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (N
oMethodError)
        from E:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/l
ib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:20:in `send'
        from E:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/l
ib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:20:in`initialize'
        from E:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/l
ib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:14:in `each'
        from E:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/l
ib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:14:in`initialize'
        from E:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/l
ib/bundler/definition.rb:43:in `new'
        from E:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/l
ib/bundler/definition.rb:43:in`initialize'

What cause this error?
I found that answer,because the old version project can't run on the new version.

Comment: what are the contents of your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files?

Answer (score 0):

You're troubling the trouble by using a legacy environment like InstantRails for rails3.

InstantRails hasn't been updated for nearly 3 years and its latest version includes ruby 1.8.6 which is incomplatible with rails 3.
From the official Ruby on Rails website:

*We recommend Ruby 1.8.7 or Ruby 1.9.2 for use with Rails. Ruby 1.8.6 and earlier are not supported, neither is version 1.9.1*

If you really insist on using windows as a development environment, the recommended way of getting rails 3 to work on Windows right now is to install ruby via the Windows installer: http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167 and then just install RubyGems by running its installation script and afterwards install rails3 as gem.